# Checking parent properties for null before binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am currently trying to find a way to check if a parent property is null before binding to a sub property, like this:

```
...{Binding Item.Text}
```

Is there a way to check if `Item` is null before accessing the `Text` property? As it stands right now I get a `NullReferenceException` in `PresentationFramework.dll` which crashes the app.

This is particularly strange as I set the Item in the ViewModel constructor and have verified that it exists before the rendering step begins:

```
public MyViewModel()
{
    Item = new Foo();
    Item.Text = "Bar";
}
```

Comment: Use a value converters. You'd get the idea.

Comment: converters only access the subproperty, not the parent property

Comment: Binding errors should not crash the application. It silently fails. You must be having a problem elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a viewmodel property for the model property you want to expose.

Since the example you've shown works for me..

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.DataContext = new MyViewModel();
    }
}

public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private Foo item;

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        Item = new Foo();
        Item.Item = "Bar";
    }

    public Foo Item
    {
        get
        {
            return this.item;
        }
        set
        {
            this.item = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Item");
        }
    }

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public string Item { get; set; }
}

<TextBox Width="200" Height="30" Text="{Binding Item.Item, Mode=TwoWay}" TextAlignment="Center"/>
```

You can expose the subproperty and perform the checking like this..

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private Foo item;

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        //Item = new Foo();
        //Item.Item = "Bar";
    }

    public Foo Item
    {
        get
        {
            return this.item;
        }
        set
        {
            this.item = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Item");
        }
    }

    public string Bar
    {
        get
        {
            if(Item == null)
            {
                return "Item is null. OMG!";
            }
            else
            {
                return Item.Item;
            }
        }
        set
        {
            Item.Item = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Bar");
        }
    }

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}

<TextBox Width="200" Height="30" Text="{Binding Bar}" TextAlignment="Center"/>
```

With this, you might want to change your view model design.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't the cause of the issue, My viewmodel is already setup similar to that. The actual cause of the issue has to do with my use of a contenttemplateselector being used to display different UI. When I switch from one template to another, the binding on the previous template gets queried first and throws the null reference exception. I was just trying to keep the question succinct, but I may have to post a new question with full details. I was just hoping there was a simpler answer

Comment: That's one more reason why it is easier to use frameworks such as MVVM Cross, etc. which cuts the crap of having to deal with these kinds of issues.

Comment: I mean the application is already very large and has worked great for me so far, this is just a weird issue with the order ContentTemplateSelector is choosing to evaluate bindings. Let me put the proper question up, its a just a bit more verbose. I'll leave this one up too since if someone has an easier solution to this it will be handy for the future